# How do I start a new Laravel project in PhpStorm 2020.3.1 on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I'm new to PHP and Laravel and am currently having trouble installing Laravel on PhpStorm 2020.3.1 and using it.

I installed it as a plugin but I'm not sure how to start a new project with it. Do i use it by starting a new composer project? I followed the tutorials online but its based on Mac. I use Windows and they made it look so easy on a Mac.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows

Comment: You can try using https://laragon.org/

Comment: Create a new project using composer (see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#installation-via-composer). Once the project is created, launch PhpStorm and use "Open" and point to the projects root folder -- it will create a new PhpStorm project from those existing files. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/laravel.html

Answer (score 1):

If your computer already has PHP and Composer installed, you may create a new Laravel project by using Composer directly. After the application has been created, you may start Laravel's local development server using the Artisan CLI's serve command:

composer create-project laravel/laravel your projectname

cd your projectname

php artisan serve